# I am unable to select the Date picker. An error message is occur

Tags: selenium

Here is my code. when i am trying to execute the script then error message is shown. I am trying to select a date picker from excel where all the method have been saved. I have prepared a excel and fetched all the method from excel and execute the script but every time an error message is shown and can't select the date picker.

```
    package com.rmspl.multiplemethod;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class MethodSet {

        static WebElement element;

        public void login (String username,String password,String nr,WebDriver fd) throws InterruptedException {



        fd.get("http://msrtc.indiagis.org");    
        fd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



        WebElement E1 = fd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'VMS')]"));
        E1.click();

        WebElement E2 = fd.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
        E2.sendKeys(username);

        WebElement E3= fd.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
        E3.sendKeys(password);

        WebElement E4 = fd.findElement(By.name("log"));
        E4.click();

        }

      public void clickLink(String xPath,String nr,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
            new WebDriverWait(fd,90).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loading_bg")));
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fd,90);
            element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
            element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
            element.click();
        }


       public void Select(String xPath,String val,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
            Select sel = new Select(fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)));
            sel.selectByValue(val);
        }

       public void Sendkey(String xPath, String val, String nr1,WebDriver fd){
           element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
           element.sendKeys(val);
       }
     public void checkbox(String xPath, String nr, String nr1,WebDriver fd){
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fd,20);
    element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
      element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
      if(!element.isSelected())
      element.click();
  }
    }


package com.rmspl.multiplemethod;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
public class TestDriver {
    static WebElement element;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, 
    NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, 
    IllegalAccessException,IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    MethodSet mt = new MethodSet();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-web-security"); 
    options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server"); 
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false); 
    prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false); 
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); 

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Arijit 
    Mohanty\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver fd = new ChromeDriver(options);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arijit 
    Mohanty\\Desktop\\Bangla\\HybridDatasheet.xls");
    Workbook WB = Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet Sh = WB.getSheet("Sheet2");

    int rows = Sh.getRows();
    int cols = Sh.getColumns();

    for (int i = 1; i<rows; i++)
        {
        String methodname = Sh.getCell(0, i).getContents();
        String data1 = Sh.getCell(1, i).getContents();
        String data2 = Sh.getCell(2, i).getContents();
        String data3 = Sh.getCell(3, i).getContents();

        Method m1 =  mt.getClass().getMethod(methodname, 
        String.class,String.class,String.class, WebDriver.class);
        m1.invoke(mt,data1,data2,data3,fd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share error / stack trace of error ? We can identify error more accurately.

Comment: @Sagar007, After execute the script then this error message is occur...               
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //img[@id='mnth_icon'] (tried for 90 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Here is my xpath which is set in excel file //img[@id='mnth_icon']

Comment: I got your point. But which line throws error that we want to identify.

Comment: @Sagar007, This line i.e line no 50 "element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));  showing an error message after execute the script.

Comment: Can you give calling line of this method `public void clickLink(String xPath,String nr,String nr1,WebDriver fd)` You have not included that code. How it possible to error in that line ?

Comment: Here is my code-public void clickLink(String xPath,String nr,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fd,90);
new WebDriverWait(fd,90).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loading_bg")));   element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
element.click();

Comment: Arijit I got you write your method. But where do you use / call the method. Refer this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Comment: @Sagar sorry for late reply.after following your advice then an error message is occur. Error is -"element not visible"

Comment: Which element is not visible ?

Comment: click element is not visible.when i am trying to select date picker.

Comment: Arijit , I hope you are having little idea about exception in java. You can find exact line or exact code of error from it. Please search your file name in that. here you will have that element. Tell that same element

Comment: This would help you to get exception line https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0ks0CDWPXg

Comment: @Thanks Sagar007 for your help. I have changed my code and got the same error. here is my new code.. public void clickLink(String xPath,String nr,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fd,90);
new WebDriverWait(fd,90).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loading_bg")));
element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
element.click();
 }

Comment: for your help please visit http://192.168.0.199/vms_test.Username-jalna, Password-12345. click into Vehicle Management>1st operate the first radio button function and try to select the date picker from 2nd radio button then this error is occur. can you help me for solve the error for the time being.

Comment: It is local URL. I think it is visible element issue. First make your element visible then try your code.

Comment: you can visit msrtc.indiagis.org.Username-jalna, Password-12345.click into Vehicle Management>1st operate the first radio button function and try to select the date picker from 2nd radio button then this error is occur. can you help me for solve the error for the time being.

Comment: Invalid username password

Comment: @sagar007, Extremely sorry. please follow the step.1.type the url msrtc.indiagis.org, 2. click into vms link. 3. type username- jalna.4.type password-12345.5.Click into vechile managemant module. 6. select 1st radio button(script working properly for first radio button). 7. when select 2nd radio button and try to select datepicker through script then error message occur.

Comment: I have seen this. It is take some time to load the element and you have not put any wait to load form. try to use different wait in selenium http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

Comment: Thanks @sagar for your help. I have solved my code. now it working correctly..

Comment: Can I write answer ?